# Why internet explorer sends Button in form POST?

Tags: html, django, internet-explorer, post

I have a pretty simple question. I am trying to find a reason why `Internet Explorer` sends `<button>` as parameter of `POST` request to the server?

### Code

```
<form method="POST" action"./" name="request_form">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="text" name="email">

    <button name="jack" type="search_form" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>

</form>
```

in this code I am getting `name, email and jack` in my `POST`. Why is that? 
It's working fine in `Firefox` or `chrome`.

Comment: Firstly, I would not use <button> inside a form. I would use <input type="button"/> or <input type="submit"/> as the former can cause issues. Secondly, if you remove the name attribute from your button what happens?

Comment: it still sends it in the POST without the name. i mean the name is empty and value is also empty.

Comment: Apparently IE implicitly treats buttons inside a form as submit buttons unless you put a type attribute that has any value but submit. When using input type submit all browsers still submit the value of that input.

Comment: as you said you would use <input> element, that would always be posting it in the form right?

Comment: actually i don not want that value in my POST, as i am traversing my POST, and filtering records on that bases

Comment: Just filter it out then.

Answer (score 1):

there is only three type for the button tag

```
button
reset
submit
```

but you have used  type="search_form"

try following code

```
<button name="jack" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
```

Comment: i am still getting it. it says, "": "", means empty key, and empty value.

Comment: only in Internet explorer.